# SSRS connection string from asp.net web config file

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am currently using ssrs reporting in my web application where i am retrieving connection string from a datasource which is located in the reporting server.But i want to get connection string info from web config file of my C# application.Anyone have idea how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not trivial nor all that secure in SSRS, at least as far as I know. One set up could be along these lines:

- Create a *hidden* parameter `@ConnString` in your report.
- Use a [Data Source Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to set the connection: `=@ConnString`.
- To make sure the report can be run with such a dynamic connection string you may need to [enable the unattended execution account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156302.aspx).

You haven't specified in the question how you're showing the report. Assuming you're using the WebForms ReportViewer you will need to inject the parameter programmatically upon loading.

Note that this setup can be quite insecure, depending on the network route your requests from the web server to the report server take.